# Postgresql: select distinct - combinations of columns

Tags: postgresql, select, distinct-values

I have this query in PostgreSQL:

```
select p1.id, p2.id, p1.title, p2.title 
from publication "p1", publication "p2"
where p1.title = p2.title and p1.id <> p2.id
```

The problem is that it returns more data than I need:

```
id    id   title          title  
3456  5678 Ulysses        Ulysses  
5678  3456 Ulysses        Ulysses  
234,  345  Das Kapital    Das Kapital  
345   234  Das Kapital    Das Kapital
```

I only need rows 1 and 3, or rows 2 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select p1.id, p2.id
 , p1.title, p2.title
from publication p1
    , publication p2
where p1.title = p2.title
  and p1.id < p2.id -- tie breaker
  ;
```

Or with the much hipper JOIN-syntax:

```
SELECT p1.id, p2.id
 , p1.title, p2.title
FROM publication p1
JOIN publication p2 ON p1.title = p2.title
                   AND p1.id < p2.id -- tie breaker
  ;
```

Comment: It seems to work. And do I understand it right: When you have the smaller than sign one of the two rows are left out, because one of the two must have a value bigger than the other. Thats the idea right?

Comment: You want to find pairs with the same title. But the original query finds **items** that are part of such a pair. And for every pair there are two such members, so you can choose an arbitrary way of supressing one of the two pair-members, such as `p1.id < p2.id`

Comment: But you should realise that if there are more then two members of a same-title group, the result will still show more than one row (eg, for triplets: it will show {1,2} and {2,3} and {1,3})

Answer (score 0):

I have simple idea to implement your scenario.

```
select p1.id, p2.id, p1.title, p2.title , sum(p1.id + p2.id) as temp
from publication "p1", publication "p2" group by temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT p1.id, p2.id, p1.title, p2.title 
from publication "p1", publication "p2"
where p1.title = p2.title
```

Comment: Please add some explanation along with your code to help the OP solve her/his problem.